# IF Statement with Three Conditions Including VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I'm trying to write an if statement that includes a `VLOOKUP`, `ISBLANK`, and `ISERROR`, `AND` separate sheets.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,'Sheet2'!$S$1:$T$9999,2,FALSE),"Scrub")
```

The above formula is working fine except that when `column F` is blank it enters "Scrub". I want to add an `ISBLANK` statement so that if `Column F` is blank it returns a blank. I know to get a blank return I enter "" but I can't seem to get it to work. I keep getting the too many arguments error.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(F2<>"", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,'Sheet2'!$S$1:$T$9999,2,FALSE),"Scrub"), "")
```

Comment: oh thank god for you Tim, I thought my brain was going to explode. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MarissaGordon If you found the answer useful then mark it as accepted so that other user can know that your problem is solved.